# XeLaTeX doesn't have complete fonts

Tags: font, latex

I've just moved to OS X form Ubuntu. I'm using OS X 10.8.2 unfortunately I'm not able to say what TeX distribution is installed on the computer since it wasn't me who installed it, I guess it was installation form tug.org.

I have problem with my `.tex` files. While LaTeX documents are compiled correctly, XeLateX generate a warning:

> Missing character: There is no ẖ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text
>   !

All other diacritics signes are found (`\d{h}`, `\b{d}` etc).

I was compiling file in TeXworks and TeXshop and I guess it's not a problem of editor since in both editors I get the same warning.

If LaTeX is using special fonts installed in it's directory, XeLaTeX is supposed to use the fonts available in general in the system.

Thanks

Here is the output of the content of `/Applications/TeX` directory:

```
MacBook-Pro-Marek:TeX user$ ls
BibDesk.app             LaTeXiT.app             TeXShop.app
Eps-Tiff-Conversion.pdf LuaTeX-and-XeTeX        TeXworks.app
Excalibur-4.0.7         READ ME FIRST.pdf       What Is Installed.pdf
FixMacTeX2012.pkg       TeX Live Utility.app
```

Comment: Do you have an `/Applications/TeX` folder with a config app? Can you run this and try to fix your installation? And to avoid a lot of guessing in case it doesn't help: Can you ask whoever installed TeX which distribution (s)he installed?

Comment: @patrix I can't see config app. For the moment I'm not able to know for sure how it was installed...

Comment: Ah, have a look into READ ME FIRST and note the date. Then run TeX Live Utility to update your installation.

Comment: @patrix Thanks. If you could tell me how should I run TeX Live Utility as a root. For the moment I've updated tlmgr (`sudo tlmgr update --self but it seems that I should also run TeX Live Utility as a root.

Comment: @patrix This is part of .log file: `2012-12-01 10:07:05 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment _checkForRootPrivileges][640] Root permission required for installation at /usr/local/texlive/2012`

Comment: Root shouldn't be necessary, running as an Administrator is enough

Comment: @patrix I've run TeX Live Utility. I'm not sure how does it work, but I guess it has updated some packages. Still I have this warning when I try to compile `.tex`, and still in the output there is white space in places of ẖ...

Comment: @patrix The problem was solved on tex.stackexchange: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85061/xelatex-on-os-x-doesnt-recognise-some-diacritics-signs#comment182958_85061]. Should the question be closed or redirected to tex.stackexchange?

Comment: Unfortunately, we're unable to close questions as duplicates of questions on other sites, so it would be great if you could summarize the answer as an answer to this question and credit/link to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the fonts I was trying to use this particular diacritic sing doesn't exist. Solution given to me on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is to add this character in the preamble of `.tex` document. The code for simple `XeLaTeX` document containing `ẖ` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E96}{\b}{h}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\b}[1]
{\hmode@bgroup\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
\vbox to.2ex{\hbox{\char"AF}\vss}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{ẖ}{\b{h}}

\begin{document}

\b{h}ur\=u\v g

\end{document}
```

Other possibility is to install fonts, like [Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org), which do have this character.

To see all question and original reply and comments, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85061/xelatex-on-os-x-doesnt-recognise-some-diacritics-signs).